# Is there a difference between `board[x, y]` and `board[x][y]` in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I'm working through a [tutorial on GeekforGeeks website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-implementation-automatic-tic-tac-toe-game-using-random-number/) and noticed that they are checking a point in an array using `board[x,y]`, which I've never seen before. I don't think this would work, but when I run the program, everything goes as expected.

I tried running a smaller code example using their method outlined above vs the method I'm more familiar with (`board[x][y]`), but when I run my code, I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

My code:

```py
board = [[1,1,1], [1,2,2], [1,2,2]]
win = 'True'

if board[1][1] == 2:
    win = 'True by normal standards'
    print(win)
if board[1, 1] == 2:
    win = 'True by weird standards'
    print(win)

print(win)
```

Their code:

```py
def row_win(board, player): 
    for x in range(len(board)): 
        win = True

        for y in range(len(board)): 
            if board[x, y] != player: 
                win = False
                continue

        if win == True: 
            return(win) 
    return(win)
```

Can someone explain to me why `board[x,y]` works, and what exactly is happening? I've never seen this before except to create lists, and am not grasping it conceptually.

Comment: If you run in interactive mode (`python -i`), then `type(board)` will show you what type `board` is (`numpy.ndarray` or `pandas.DataFrame`). Or look at the lines that create and initialize `board`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They're able to do that since they're using NumPy, which won't throw an error on that.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,2,2], [1,2,2]])
>>> a[1,1]
2
>>> # equivalent to
>>> a = [[1,1,1], [1,2,2], [1,2,2]]
>>> a[1][1]
2
>>>
```

Comment: And is it the same in numpy? Or is one of the two (significantly) more performant or in any other way preferable?

Comment: @lucidbrot: `a[1,1]` would be more performant in `numpy`, as it avoids creating additional `numpy` array wrappers; `a[1][1]` has to load `a`, index to `1`, creating a wrapper for that row, then index to `1` on that row to get the cell's value, then clean up the wrapper. `a[1,1]` directly loads the cell's value without creating additional wrapper objects (it does have to make a `tuple` on demand if the indices aren't constant, but small `tuple` literals are specially optimized in Python, so the cost is pretty small).

Answer (score 13):

That works because the object they are using (in this case numpy array) overloads the `__getitem__` method. See this toy example:

```
class MyArray:
  def __init__(self, arr):
    self.arr = arr
  def __getitem__(self, t):
    return self.arr[t[0]][t[1]]

myarr = MyArray([[1,1,1], [1,2,2], [1,2,2]])
print(myarr[0,1])
```

Answer (score 8):

It does not actually work in base Python (like your example). If you run your code, Python throws an exception: 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'.

The `1, 1` passed to `board` is interpreted as a tuple and since board should be indexed with integers or slices, this won't work.

However, if `board` were some type of array-like data structure and the developer had implemented support for indexing with tuples, this would work. An example of this is arrays in `numpy`.

Comment: Don't say *"It does not actually work."* You mean *"It does not actually work **in base Python**, if `board` is a list-of-lists*.

Comment: I felt that was implied, given the example under discussion, but I've updated the answer.

Comment: Grismar the OP is clearly unaware of numpy/pandas, and not in the habit of doing `type(board)` to actually see what type of object it is. You might think that's all implied for advanced users, but it sure ain't for new users.

Comment: Even the updated answer falsely implies that this won’t work without third-party libraries, whereas it clearly does: Code as trivial as `x = {}; x[1, 1] = 42` works as expected. Or, more to the point, nothing forbids somebody to implement a 2D array class in base Python with very little code.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - the example you're giving is a dictionary that would be indexed with a tuple. That's not just a horrible anti-pattern, but also clearly not what the OP is asking about. I agreed to a point with what smci was saying - it may have been unclear that I meant base python; many libraries actually implement arrays with multi-dimensional indices. However, the example you provide shows that doing so is not at all trivial and certainly not base Python. Finally, if a required solution would be best realised with a dict indexed with tuples, that's perfectly in line with my answer.

Comment: @Grismar No, it’s neither an anti-pattern (look up how sparse arrays are implemented!), nor is it (necessarily) not what OP is asking (again, sparse arrays). More importantly, it fits in a comment, whereas a custom class written in base Python doesn’t. Either way, your answer implies that this syntax requires special libraries and that’s patently not the case. Even with a custom class it takes <20 lines of code to implement this efficiently.

Comment: @KonradRudolph nowhere did I suggest you need 'special' libraries, or that the number of lines would exceed a few well-written ones. If the OP had asked about sparse arrays you answer would be the correct one. I'm not sure what your point here is, but apparently it can only be won by putting words in people's mouths. Libraries are (or can be) written in Python, so if your point is that you can write a solution in Python that works as described, then congratulations, we can agree that Python is a normal, mature programming language. But in base Python, as it comes from the tin, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Grismar You seem to have an odd, overly restrictive definition of what “base Python” is (apparently it’s only `list` without any added code?). My comment shows how to use the syntax from OP’s question in pure base Python. I am baffled how you continue to argue with this simple fact.

Comment: @KonradRudolph no more baffled that I am by your insistence to put words in people's mouths to belabour a point that has very little merit to begin with. Yes, you can write Python code to make the example in OP's code work, easily. That's not at all the point - in base Python, the index operator typically expects single integers to index a sequence and the same operator is used to access other data structures like dict. Yes, you can use dict to implement sparse arrays, or implement other means of access - but the examples given by OP make it pretty clear in what context the question was asked.

Answer (score 5):

The `board[x, y]` syntax is probably being applied onto a numpy array, which accepts this syntax in order to implement row/column indexed slicing operations. Take a look at these examples:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])  # creates 2D array
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

>>> x[1]  # get second row (remember, index starts at 0)
array([4, 5, 6])

>>> x[:, 2]  # get third column
array([3, 6, 9])

>>> x[1, 2]  # get element on second row, third column
6

>>> x[1][2]  # same as before but with non-broadcasting syntax (i.e. works for lists as you are used to)
6

>>> x[1, 0:2]  # get first two elements of second row  
array([4, 5])

>>> x[0:2, 0:2]  # subsets the original array, "extracting" values from the first two columns/rows only
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

Of course, writing `my_list[x, y]` throws an error because `x, y` is actually a tuple `(x, y)`, and regular lists can't work with tuples as an indexing value.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to NumPy, so this is extremely useful

Answer (score 5):

**Because their `board` is either `numpy.ndarray` or some type that wraps it, e.g. `pandas.DataFrame`** `board[x,y]` is pandas 2D indexing, not base Python.

You should have done `type(board)`. Or show us the lines that create and initialize `board`.

Also, when you say "when I run the program, everything goes as expected", you should run in interactive mode (`python -i`), then you could run queries like `type(board)` (or in iPython/jupyter type `whos` to see alist of variables and their types)

Answer (score 2):

In python, `[]` is `__getitem__`, which can be easily rewritten.

And, `1, 2` in python will give us a tuple. yes, we don't really need `()` to create a non empty tuple.

So, Numpy can do this very easily, even I can.

```
In [1]: 1, 1
Out[1]: (1, 1)

In [2]: type(_)
Out[2]: tuple

In [3]: a = {(1, 1): 3}

In [4]: a[1, 1]
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: a[(1, 1)]
Out[5]: 3

In [6]: class NumpyArray(list):
   ...:     def __getitem__(self, index):
   ...:         if isinstance(index, tuple) and len(index) == 2:
   ...:             return self[index[0]][index[1]]
   ...:         return super().__getitem__(index)
   ...:

In [7]: b = NumpyArray([[0, 1], [2, 3]])

In [8]: b[1, 1]
Out[8]: 3
```

You can use below code to try on your own iPython.

```
class NumpyArray(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if isinstance(index, tuple) and len(index) == 2:
            return self[index[0]][index[1]]
        return super().__getitem__(index)

b = NumpyArray([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
b[1, 1]
```